# Как хранить перечисления в базе данных?

Tags: android, sqlite

Хочу что-бы можно было в базе хранить перечисление id-шников другой таблицы. Но не знаю как грамотно это организовать. Я так понимаю что тип столбца должен быть Text, а при добавлении использовать разделитель и как-то потом это дело разбивать на эти самые id. Подскажите кто с этим сталкивался.

Comment: Например, строковой тип столбца и `Id` хранятся, разделенные запятой: `"1,2,3,42"`. При добавлении значения, `id` приводятся к строке, склеиваются в строку с разделителем `,`. А при вытаскивании обратное действие -- разделение по `,` и приведение `id` к числу

Comment: Как можна String вроде: "1, 2, 3, 4" разбить на массив int[]{1,2,3,4}?

Comment: `String[] parts = string.split(", ");` после в цикле проходите по `parts`, конвертируя в число

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Предложенное решение - знатный костыль. Есть такая дисциплина - СУБД, если вы хотите работать с БД "по взрослому", вам необходимо ознакомиться с этой наукой вообще и с организацией связи "многие ко многим" в частности. Для начала рекомендую почитать книгу [Л.Бейли "Изучаем SQL"](http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=159318&view=findpost&p=33907811). Книга дает все основные понятия работы с БД и написана очень доступно для новичков.